# Given integer array and an integer k find all values that add up to k

Tags: python, algorithm

```
def listIntergerSum(lst,desiredValue):
    seen = set()
    output = set()
    for listValue in lst:
        target = desiredValue - listValue
        print("{} = {} - {} ".format(target,desiredValue,listValue))

        if target not in seen:

            seen.add(listValue)
            
        
        else:
            output.add((min(listValue,target),max(listValue,target)))
            print("Added to output : ",output)
    print("\n".join(map(str,list(output))))

listIntergerSum([1,-7,2,4,5,10,3,3,3,9],9)
```

In the above code the output gets derived out of only two integers. So if k is 9 then output will only be (4,5) , what changes do i need to make so that (3,3,3) is also a valid output without increasing the time complexity (adding another for loop).

Comment: Are you looking for contiguous sequences, or subsets?

Comment: Without increasing the time complexity which is currently O(n)? I'm afraid that is not possible, as I think there can be more than O(n) results which have to be printed. Example: `[-1,1,-2,2,-3,3, ..., -x,x]` and `k=0` has *at least* 2^x = 2^(n/2) results.

Comment: @AbhinavMathur The current solution implies subsets, as it also pairs non-contiguous values.

Comment: @Socowi how? `4,5` and `3,3,3` are contiguous

Comment: Your task is subset sum, it's NP-complete and not possible (still) with polynomial time, for more reading I suggest this : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subset_sum_problem

Comment: @AbhinavMathur With *solution* I meant OP's current implementation, not the expected results. Run OP's program for the input `listIntergerSum([1,2,3], 4)` and you get `(1, 3)`.

Comment: I downvoted because OP did not react to any questions or hints. I would be happy to remove the downvote if the question is refined.

Comment: @Socowi I got the answer from your first comment. It is not possible to get extra subset solutions without adding another for loop.